# import and call a function with es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Previously:

```
var debug = require('debug')('http')
  , http = require('http')
  , name = 'My App';
```

With es6, how can I import and invoke right away like the first line?

```
import debug from 'debug'();
```

is a no no?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You'll need two lines:

```
import debugModule from 'debug';
const debug = debugModule('http');
```

The import syntax is a declarative import syntax, it does not execute any functions.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes you need to call the function before any other import statements. `import` does not allow the execution of other statements before all `import` statements are declared.

Comment: @user2078023 In that case it may be best to move the whole import-and-call into a separate module, which you can import when you need both to happen.

Answer (score 5):

> is a no no?

Correct. Keep in mind that the `import` statement is analogous to more than a simple `require()` statement -- it also creates a binding of the "loaded" module to a local variable.

That is,

```
import debug from 'debug'();
```

...is more close in behavior/semantics to

```
var debug = require('debug');
```

...than it is to simply

```
require('debug');
```

Analogies to commonjs-style module loaders will obviously break down at some point, but at the end of the day it's a "no no" due to the plain and simple fact that `import debug from 'debug'` doesn't actually resolve to anything that you can invoke (or otherwise reference).

Answer (score -21):

```
import http from "debug"; // not sure if this is the desired effect
```

Comment: Be sure, this doesn't have a desired effect