# Property 'Server' does not exist on type 'typeof "http"'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, socket.io, ecmascript-6

I know that `var someModule = require('someModule')` is generally replaced by `import * as someModule from 'someModule'` but I can't figure out how to use Typescript/ES6 syntax to express the following Node.js code:

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
```

After reading [import and call a function with es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599566/import-and-call-a-function-with-es6)
I have tried the following:

```
import * as httpModule from 'http';
const server = httpModule.Server(app);
```

and the code does compile and run properly but I still get this TS error:

`[ts] Property 'Server' does not exist on type 'typeof "http"'`.

I have @types/node and @types/express installed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Felix Kling I have edited my question and believe it is no longer a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599566/import-and-call-a-function-with-es6

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import { Server, createServer } from 'http';
const server = createServer(app);
```

[This might help](https://dev.to/briandgls/http-to-https-redirect-in-node).

Clarification: You are using [default import instead named import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import).

Comment: This works, thank you. But I'd like to understand why it does and my solution doesn't. Also, why import `Server` from `http` if all we are using is `createServer`? Any insights?

Comment: Check out how imports work, you are mixing up default and named imports as updated in answer.

Comment: According to the TypeScript docs, using the `*`, like I did, doesn't import default exports but rather "imports the entire module into a single variable, and uses it to access the module exports". That's why I don't understand that it doesn't work. Technically it should.

Comment: Well I don't have node set up but you should be able to check/debug what 'httpModule' contains.